# Django - Multivalue Foreign Key

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have models as follows. The `FormResponses` model is used to create form. I want to store list of all the members who were missing in the event.

Is something like `models.ForeignKeyListField` possible?
There can be zero or more members missing

```
class Member(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=200)
    ...

class FormResponses(model.Model):
    missing_members = # array of members missing
    ...
```

Comment: Would missing members not be a query you need to make? Members exclude those that attended?

Comment: @Sayse Yes. I'll query to find out how many calls each member has missed or who was missing in a particular event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're describing a many-to-many relationship (both ends of the relationship can have multiple matches). Django has a [field type ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield) which implements this.

> class ManyToManyField(othermodel, **options)
>
> A many-to-many relationship. Requires a positional argument: the class to which the model is related, which works exactly the same as it does for ForeignKey, including recursive and lazy relationships.

Answer (score 1):

ManyToManyField should answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

What you're after is a [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField).